# What is difference between arping and arp?

Tags: networking

Guys am having a mysterious doubt in diff. b/w arping and arp. When my senior asked me i was speechless. Pls. help me am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Address Resolution Protocol** - **arp** is a protocol. Its operation is usually implicit in other network activities, transparent to users. Among other things the arp protocol maintains a table of IP-to-ethernet address mappings derived from its operation. There is a related command that's also named **`arp`**. Its focus is the table, and it is a tool whereby maintenance of the arp table can be done manually.

Another command of interest is **`arping`**. It is to explicitly trigger the arp protocol to action, emitting arp packets.

Source and more about:

- [exercising the "arp" and "arping" commands](http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs75/labs/arp-and-arping.htm)

See also:

- [Address Resolution Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)
- [arping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping)